# Sharing variables between two methods in a controller?

Tags: ruby, variables, controller, scope, instance-variables

I have two methods `auth` and `notes` and I want to share a variable between them.

```
require 'rest_client'

class MynotesController < ApplicationController
  obj.instance_eval('@parsedToken')

  def auth
    username = params[:name]
    password = params[:password]
    if (username != 0)
      token = RestClient.post 'candidate.apiary.io/login', :params => {:username => username, :password => password}
      @parsedToken = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(token) 
    end
  end

  def notes

  end


end
```

What should I do if i want to access `@parsedToken` in the `notes` method?

Comment: it is an instance variable, and should be available to every instance method in an instance of the `MynotesController`

Comment: Hi, but I tried to access @parsedToken in my notes View and it is Nil.

Comment: `auth` must have been called for `@parsedToken` to exist in `notes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def notes
  "My parsed token is #{@parsed_token}"
end
```

I would probably use the Ruby style convention to use an underscore to represent space between names, rather than camelCase for names.